# How to display current section title in the header when a new chapter begins just on an odd page

Tags: fancyhdr, books

I am using package **fancyhdr** to help me construct the headers of my book. The Editor want to me to add the chapter title to the header if the new chapter begins on a page whose number is even, and to add the section title to the header if the new chapter begins on a page whose number is odd. Then I modified the page-style "plain" as follows (just a test file):

```
 \documentclass[openany]{book}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \renewcommand{\headwidth}{\textwidth} 

 \pagestyle{fancy}                        
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
 \fancyhf{}                                                 
 \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}                       
 \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}                                
 \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} 

 \fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}                                
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}                               
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}                          
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}                                
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}  
}

 \begin{document}
 \chapter{Test-1}     
 \section{test-section-1}
 \newpage
 \section{test-section-2}
 \newpage
 \section{test-section-3}
 \newpage
 \chapter{Test-2}
 \section{test-section-4}
 \end{document}
```

But I can only realize partially the specifications. If the new chapter begins on an even page, all the codes are OK, but if the new chapter begins on *odd* page, then it could not display the section title, but only the page number. Here is the screen-shoots:

1. New chapter page with ODD page number, need section title
   [image: odd page-without section title-new chapter]
2. even page, all things are OK 
   [image: even page-with chapter title]
3. odd page, all things are OK
   [image: odd page-with section title]
4. new chapter page with Even page number, all things are OK
   [image: even page-with chapter title-new chapter]

Then I tried many methods. But at last I figured out a method, which is very complex, but it did work.  I just only defined a new command, which is as follows:

```
  \newcommand{\headodd}[2]{\fancypagestyle{myplain}{%  
    \fancyhf{} %   
    \pagestyle{fancy}                               
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}                                     
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}                         
    \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}  
    %\hypersetup{   
      %  colorlinks=false,
     %   pdfborder={0 0 0},
    %}                             
    \fancyhead[LO]{ \ref{#1} #2}  
    }
   \thispagestyle{myplain}
}
```

Then I modified the main body into :

```
     \chapter{Test-1}
     \headodd{s-1}{test-section-1}
     \section{test-section-1}\label{s-1}
```

Thus I get the following result: 
[image: What I want to get]

My question is: (1) Is there any other method to satisfy all the editor's specifications?
 (2) How to simplify my codes?

Comment: did the answer below help

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Though not very familiar with the `titleps` package but after some experimentation and Google search on this website at `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208370/title-marking-with-titleps-breaks-when-tableofcontents-is-used` and thanks to `@cfr`

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{
  \sethead[\firsttitlemarks\bfseries\ifthesection{\thesection}{\ifthechapter{\chaptertitle}{\chaptertitle}}][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
  {}{}{\bottitlemarks\bfseries\ifthesection{\thesection}{\ifthechapter{\thechapter}{\chaptertitle}}}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setfoot[\thepage][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
  {}{}{\thepage}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setheadrule{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Header Test}
  \section{Sec1}
  \lipsum[1]
  \section{Sec2}
  \lipsum[3-4]
  \section{Sec3}
  \lipsum[5]
  \section{Sec4}
  \lipsum[7]
  \chapter{New Chapter}
  \section{Sec5}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Sec6}
  \lipsum[6]
  \section{Sec7}
  \lipsum[8-9]
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
  \chapter{GAH}
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \chapter{New Chapter AAAA}
  \section{Sec5}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Sec6}
  \lipsum[6]
  \section{Sec7}
  \lipsum[8-9]
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
  \chapter{GAH1}
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \chapter{New CHAPTER AAAAA}
  \section{Sec5}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Sec6}
  \lipsum[6]
  \section{Sec7}
  \lipsum[8-9]
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```