# Title marking with titleps breaks when \tableofcontents is used

Tags: fancyhdr, titleps

I asked a question about chapter/section marking in headers in a previous question, and got very helpful feedback from @Werner and @cfr. I discovered another problem when I implemented their suggestions, but I think seeking a solution to it warrants another question.

I'm new to this site, so please forgive me if I should have kept it in the comments of their answers.

I was trying to add marking that's `\thechapter`.`\thesection`, where `\thesection` is always the *first **new*** mark of the page on *even* pages, and the *last* mark of the page on odd pages. This works great in the example code, but when I apply it to the actual document it fails.

After reading logs and tinkering, I found out this happens whenever I use `\tableofcontents` in the document. When I remove `\tableofcontents` it works properly. The first page of random chapters won't show any chapter marks at all, only a header line, when I use `\tableofcontents`.

Here's the example code (comment/uncomment the `\tableofcontents` line and you'll see what I mean):

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} %i usepackage the package this way instead of {titleps} because I use both titleps and titlesec in the actual document, and the manual says i need to include titleps this way if I use both.

\renewpagestyle{plain}{
    \sethead[\firsttitlemarks\bfseries\ifnum\value{section}=0 \thechapter\else\thesection\fi][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
    {}{}{\bottitlemarks\bfseries\ifnum\value{section}=0 \thechapter\else\thesection\fi}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
    \setfoot[\thepage][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
    {}{}{\thepage}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
    \setheadrule{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Header Test CH1}
    \section{Sec1}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{Sec2}
    \lipsum[3-4]
    \section{Sec3}
    \lipsum[5]
    \section{Sec4}
    \lipsum[7]
\chapter{Header Test CH2}
    \section{Sec1}
    \lipsum[2]
    \section{Sec2}
    \lipsum[6]
    \section{Sec3}
    \lipsum[8-9]
    \section{Sec4}
    \lipsum[10]
\chapter{Header Test CH3}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{Header Test CH4}
    \section{Sec1}
    \lipsum[2]
    \section{Sec2}
    \lipsum[6]
    \section{Sec3}
    \lipsum[8-9]
    \section{Sec4}
    \lipsum[10]
\chapter{Header Test CH5}
    \section{Sec1}
    \lipsum[10]
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \lipsum[1-4]
    \lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{Header Test CH6}
    \section{Sec2}
    \lipsum[2]
    \section{Sec3}
    \lipsum[6]
    \section{Sec4}
    \lipsum[8-9]
    \section{Sec5}
    \lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

Is this a known issue with a workaround? Is there something wrong with my use of the package? Is there a way this can be fixed?

In the actual document, I also get an 'Undefined control sequence' error on the line that `\tableofcontents` is called. When I comment out the titleps lines and replace them with the fancyhdr lines, this error goes away. This might be a question for another post, but I figured I'd say it here now in case there's an obvious reason for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my [edited answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208352/) to your other question:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{
  \sethead[\firsttitlemarks\bfseries\ifthesection{\thesection}{\ifthechapter{\thechapter}{\chaptertitle}}][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
  {}{}{\bottitlemarks\bfseries\ifthesection{\thesection}{\ifthechapter{\thechapter}{\chaptertitle}}}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setfoot[\thepage][][]% even-left | even-center | even-right
  {}{}{\thepage}% odd-left | odd-center | odd-right
  \setheadrule{0.4pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Header Test}
  \section{Sec1}
  \lipsum[1]
  \section{Sec2}
  \lipsum[3-4]
  \section{Sec3}
  \lipsum[5]
  \section{Sec4}
  \lipsum[7]
  \chapter{New Chapter}
  \section{Sec5}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Sec6}
  \lipsum[6]
  \section{Sec7}
  \lipsum[8-9]
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
  \chapter{GAH}
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \chapter{New Chapter AAAA}
  \section{Sec5}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Sec6}
  \lipsum[6]
  \section{Sec7}
  \lipsum[8-9]
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
  \chapter{GAH1}
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \chapter{New CHAPTER AAAAA}
  \section{Sec5}
  \lipsum[2]
  \section{Sec6}
  \lipsum[6]
  \section{Sec7}
  \lipsum[8-9]
  \section{Sec8}
  \lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```